# Python regex to retrieve multiple values with various given words between them

Tags: python, regex, findall

Need to retrieve dimensions from the text where they can be specified in a couple of ways:

- "... 10.5 inches x 5 feet x 2 inches ..."
- "... 10 inches x 5 inches ..."
- "... 10 inches x 5 inches ..."
- "... 10 x 5 inches ..."

There can be two or three dimensions and each might have its own measurement type or not have it.

I am struggling to add the list of optional dimension types and make the search of the third vale optional in the regex:

`dimensions = re.findall(r'(\d+\.?\d*)\s*inches?feet?\s*x\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s*inches?feet?\s*x?\s*(\d+\.?\d*)?\s*inches?feet?',string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is `inches?feet?`, which says "match 0 to 1 'inches' and 0 to 1 'feet'". This means it could match something like "5 inchesfeet".

You were fairly close. The key idea you missed is that `|` can be used to specify alternatives to match: `(?:inches|feet)?`. They're put in a non-capturing group to clarify that only "feet" should be part of the alternative and not everything after it. The `?` at the end makes the entire group optional.

To make the entire third dimension optional, the pattern for it can be put in a non-capturing group, and then that group can be made optional with `?`:

```
(?:x\s*(\d+\.?\d*)?\s*(?:inches|feet)?)?
```

The final regex is

```
(\d+\.?\d*)\s*(?:inches|feet)?\s*x\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s*(?:inches|feet)?\s*(?:x\s*(\d+\.?\d*)?\s*(?:inches|feet)?)?
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. I actually tried | but it didn't work because I didn't put in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one `re.findall` approach which is working:

```py
inp = """... 10 inches x 5 feet x 2 inches ...
... 10 inches x 5 inches ..."
... 10 inches x 5 inches ..."
... 10 x 5 inches ..."""

dims = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: (?!x\b)\w+)?(?: x \d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: (?!x\b)\w+)?)*', inp)
print(dims)
```

This prints:

```
['10 inches x 5 feet x 2 inches',
 '10 inches x 5 inches',
 '10 inches x 5 inches',
 '10 x 5 inches']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern being used:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?           match a number
(?:
    [ ]                 followed by space
    (?!x\b)             NOT followed by 'x'
    \w+                 but is followed by any other dimension
)?                      optional
(?:
    [ ]                 space
    x                   'x'
    [ ]                 space
    \d+(?:\.\d+)?       another number
    (?: (?!x\b)\w+)?    zero or more other numbers/dimensions
)*                      optional
```

Comment: I forgot to say that dimensions might be decimal. For example, 10.5 inches. I used your example and made this one: r'(\d+\.?\d*)\s*\w+?\s*x\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s*\w+?\s*(\d+\.?\d*)?\s*\w+?' - it works expect for these two cases: "42.5 inches x 5 feet x 35 inches" and ""Porcelain measures 13 inches x 8 inches ungraded."  In both cases I get only first two values

Comment: Try the updated answer.